How to ensure Visual Studio configuration for xunit fact and theory have Unit Trait Cetegory
Is there a way to specify visual studio configuration which ensures xunit fact and theory unit tests flags for missing [Trait("Category", "Unit")], this is to ensure code uniformity.
Trying to find some .editorconfig configuration to flag missing Trait category

First thing that comes to my mind is writing simple code analyzer
For that you need to first modify VS to install new workload:

.NET Compiler Platform SDK

Then you need to

create project of type Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET Standard) (let's call it MissingAttributes)
in MissingAttributesAnalyzer class you need to define method that will analyze the attributes (note that is just POC, and you can enhance it):

private static void AnalyzeMethod(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    var attributes = context.Symbol.GetAttributes();

    var hasTrait = attributes.Any(x => x.AttributeClass.Name.Contains("Trait"));
    var hasFact = attributes.Any(x => x.AttributeClass.Name.Contains("Fact"));
    var hasTheory = attributes.Any(x => x.AttributeClass.Name.Contains("Theory"));
    var isTestMethod = hasFact || hasTheory;

    if(hasTrait && !isTestMethod)
    {
        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(
            new DiagnosticDescriptor(
                DiagnosticId,
                "Add test attribute",
                "Add test attribute",
                "Missing attribute",
                DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
                isEnabledByDefault: true,
                description: Description),
            context.Symbol.Locations[0], 
            context.Symbol.Name);

        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}

and register it in Initialize
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

    context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeMethod, SymbolKind.Method);
}

Now we have setup our analyzer. Now you are able to publish it and install it on your VS.
Note, that it is just POC, so it should be adjusted, for example, maybe you want to treat it as error.
References:

Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix

